# C# .NET and Lua - require "luanet" fails

Tags: c#, .net, lua, require

I am trying to use the .NET CLR with Lua. In my .lua file on the first line, I have:

require "luanet"

I can load the dll, but immediately get an error:

error loading module 'luanet' from luanet.dll:
        luanet.dll:1: '=' expected near "

I have searched the Internet and I have downloaded and tried 3 different versions of this luanet.dll and I got the same error on all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem, although I am not sure it was the best solution. All I did was change the Build setting "Platform target" from "Any CPU" to "x86" and rebuild the luanet DLL and LuaInterface assembly. I also had to change that same build selection to "x86" in the C# application where I was using the LuaInterface assembly.

If someone know of a better or more eloquent solution, please pass it along.

Answer (score 0):

I almost forget - I also had to explicitly set the "package.path" in the Lua script to the place where the "luanet.dll" lives. Although the path in the LUA_PATH environmental variable had that correct path, for some reason I still had to set it in the Lua script before the line:

require 'luanet'

Comment: You should combine this and your other answer and accept it.  You should also put the full details of what you set the paths to (something like `package.path = DATA_DIR .. "\\lua\\?.lua;" .. package.path` for example)